# Getting assembly error when attempting to process cube in VS-2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I'm trying to set up a BI solution, but I'm running into a problem. After I create a new cube, I right-click 'Process Cube...' and I get the following 'assembly is missing' error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'SqlMgmt, Version=12.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And then VS2012 restarts itself. Obviously I'm missing some assembly, but I'm not sure how to get it installed.

I'm using the CTP2 version of SSDT-BI with Visual Studio 2012 as recommended by Microsoft here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

I just needed to install SSDT for SQL Server 2012 and SSDT for SQL Server 2014. I don't know which one fixed it, but it now appears to be fixed.

Relevant links are here:

SSDT 2012: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/13/available-today-ssdt-december-2012.aspx

SSDT 2014: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/03/25/sql-server-data-tools-for-sql-server-2014-is-available.aspx